# Any way for conan to automatically upload package to artifactory IF it was just built with --build=missing

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory, conan

if a package was freshly built with the --build=missing I want to cache the package into our local artifactory server

For instance, the build of grpc 32 bit that our jenkins is performing takes 40-60 minutes, and we want to only run it once for a given version of grpc

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `package-list` feature can capture the result of a build, create a list of packages that can be provided to the `conan upload` command.

Something like:

```
# the build
$conan install --requires="spdlog/[*]" --build="*" --format=json > build.json

# creating a package list from the dependency graph from the build
$ conan list --graph=build.json --graph-binaries=build --format=json > pkglist.json

# uploading the package list
$ conan upload --list=pkglist.json -r=myremote -c
```

More details in https://blog.conan.io/2023/06/28/Conan-bulk-package-operations.html

Comment: that is interesting, I will try it. I will have to be logged in, which our jenkins machine is currently not. operated only read mode.

Comment: additionally, is there a way to conditionally check if a --build=missing has been triggered? and THEN to run conan list and conan upload?

Comment: You can run them always. If the resulting list is empty, because nothing was built from source, it will upload nothing, not need to make it conditional. Or if you want to really check, just do a ``jq`` over the ``pkglist.json`` to check it contents.